# How to optimize a simple loop?

Tags: c++, optimization, vectorization, multicore, simd

The loop is simple

```
void loop(int n, double* a, double const* b)
{
#pragma ivdep
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i, ++a, ++b)
        *a *= *b;
}
```

I am using intel c++ compiler and using `#pragma ivdep` for optimization currently. Any way to make it perform better like using multicore and vectorization together, or other techniques?

Comment: Have you checked the generated assembly? I know some compilers will auto vectorize simple loops. Its possible it already has been.

Comment: Memory is going to be the bottleneck. What's the point of using multiple cores?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Do you think using GPU will get better performance?

Comment: GPU isnt a magic solution, you have to take into account that the data needs to be transfered to and from the GPU which takes a while. So its possible it might help, but it could also be worse.

Comment: I'm not faimiliar with it, but logic dictates it's the same issue. If you want a boost, the memory has to reside on the GPU.

Comment: It the memory is going to be the bottleneck depends on the way, the workload is distributed, and on the number of cores that share the same memory block. The workload has to be distributed to the CPU cores in larger chunks, so that burst reads/writes and preloading cache lines does help on every core. That should theoretically scale quite well to the typical size of a NUMA node (usually up to 8 cores). When you distribute the workload on more than one NUMA node, consider to explicitly copy the chunks of data for each thread to the node it works on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This loop is absolutely vectoriz*able* by compiler. But make sure that loop was actually vectorized (using Compiler' -qopt-report5, assembly output,  [Intel (vectorization) Advisor](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-advisor-xe), whatever other techniques). One more overkill way to do that is creating *performance baseline* using -no-vec option (which will disable ivdep-driven and auto-vectorization) and then compare execution time against it. This is not good way for checking vectorization presence, but it's useful for general performance analysis for next bullets.

If loop hasn't been actually vectorized, make sure you push compiler to auto-vectorize it. In order to push compiler see next bullet. Note that next bullet could be useful even if loop was succesfully auto-vectorized.

2. To push compiler to vectorize it use: (a) **restrict** keyword to "disambiguate" a and b pointers (someone has already suggested it to you). (b) **#pragma omp simd** (which has extra bonus of being more portable and much more flexible than ivdep, but also has a drawback of being unsupported in old compilers before intel compiler version 14 and for other loops is more "dangerous"). To re-emphasize: given bullet may seem to do the same thing as ivdep, but depending on various circumstances it could be better and more powerful option.
3. Given loop has fine-grain iterations (too small amount of computations per single iteration) and overall is not purely compute-bound (so effort/cycles spent by CPU to load/store data from/to cache/memory is comparable if not bigger to effort/cycles spent to perform multiplication). Unrolling is often good way to slightly mitigate such disadvantages. But I would recommend to explicitly ask compiler to unroll it, by using **#pragma unroll**. In fact, for certain compiler versions the unrolling will happen automatically. Again, you can check whenever compiler did it by using -qopt-report5, loop assembly or Intel (Vectorization) [Advisor](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-advisor-xe):
   [image]
4. In given loop you deal with "streaming" access pattern. I.e. you are contiguously loading/store data from/to memory (and cache sub-system will not help a lot for big "n" values). So, depending on target hardware, usage of multi-threading (atop of SIMD), etc, your loop will likely become memory bandwidth bound in the end. Once you become memory **bandwidth bound**, you could use techniques like *loop blocking, non-temporal stores, aggressive prefetching.* All of these techniques worth separate article, although for prefetching/NT-stores you have some pragmas in Intel Compiler to play with.
5. If n is huge, and you already got prepared to memory bandwidth troubles, you could use things like **#pragma omp parallel for simd**, which will simulteneously thread-parallelize and vectorize the loop. However quality of this feature has been made decent only in very fresh compiler versions AFAIK, so maybe you'd prefer to split n semi-manually. I.e. **n=n1xn2xn3**, where n1 - is number of iterations to distribute among threads, n2 - for cache blocking, n3 - for vectorization. Rewrite given loop to make it loopnest of 3 nested loops, where outer loop has n1 iterations (and #pragma omp parallel for is applied), next level loop has n2 iterations, n3 - is innermost (where #pragma omp simd is applied).

**Some up to date links with syntax examples and more info**:

- unroll: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoid-manual-loop-unrolling
- OpenMP SIMD pragma (not so fresh and detailed, but still relevant):  https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/enabling-simd-in-program-using-openmp40
- [restrict vs. ivdep](https://books.google.com/books?id=KJORYTHOxbEC&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128&dq=restrict%20ivdep%20intel%20compiler&source=bl&ots=y7A6ljdmZx&sig=ivNPpMM2DdHQNlEWG7aoO-XevmA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip5tCnjfDJAhVHoA4KHSmQCC8Q6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=restrict%20ivdep%20intel%20compiler&f=false)
- NT-stores and prefetching : https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/22/a3/mtaap2013-prefetch-streaming-stores.pdf

Note1: I apologize that I don't provide various code snippets here. There are at least 2 justifiable reasons for not providing them here: 1. My 5 bullets are pretty much applicable to very many kernels, not just to yours. 2. On the other hand specific combination of pragmas/manual rewriting techniques and corresponding performance results will vary depending on target platform, ISA and Compiler version.

Note2: Last comment regarding your GPU question. Think of your loop vs. simple industry benchmarks like LINPACK or STREAM. In fact your loop could become somewhat very similar to some of them in the end. Now think of x86 CPUs and especially Intel Xeon Phi platform characteristics for LINPACK/STREAM. They are very good indeed and will become even better with High Bandwidth Memory platforms (like Xeon Phi 2nd gen). So theoretically there is no any single reason to think that *your given loop* is not well mapped to at least some variants of x86 hardware (note that I didn't say similar thing for *arbitrary kernel in universe*).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data pointed to by `a` can't overlap the data pointed to by `b` the most important information to give the compiler to let it optimize the code is that fact.

In older ICC version "restrict" was the only clean way to provide that key information to the compiler.  In newer versions there are a few cleaner ways to give a much stronger guarantee than `ivdep` gives (in fact `ivdep` is a weaker promise to the optimizer than it appears and generally doesn't have the intended effect).

But if `n` is large, the whole thing will be dominated by the cache misses, so no local optimization can help.

Comment: Sorry, I remember concepts from the presentation we got from Intel, but I don't recall syntax.  I can't use it myself because my employer decided we need to keep MSVC compatibility.  Is `n` small enough that you don't think cache misses will dominate?

Answer (score 1):

**Loop unrolling manually** is a simple way to optimize your code, and following is my code. Original `loop` costs 618.48 ms, while `loop2` costs 381.10 ms in my PC, the compiler is GCC with option '-O2'. I don't have Intel ICC to verify the code, but I think the optimization principles are the same.

Similarly, I did some experiments that compare the execution time of two programs to XOR two blocks of memories, and one program is vectorized with the help of SIMD instructions, while the other is manually loop-unrolled. If you are interested, see [here](https://github.com/foool/AVT).

P.S. Of course `loop2` only works when n is even.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define LEN 512*1024
#define times  1000

void loop(int n, double* a, double const* b){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i, ++a, ++b)
        *a *= *b;
}

void loop2(int n, double* a, double const* b){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i=i+2, a=a+2, b=b+2)
        *a *= *b;
        *(a+1) *= *(b+1);
}


int main(void){
    double *la, *lb;
    struct timeval begin, end;
    int i;

    la = (double *)malloc(LEN*sizeof(double));
    lb = (double *)malloc(LEN*sizeof(double));
    gettimeofday(&begin, NULL);
    for(i = 0; i < times; ++i){
        loop(LEN, la, lb);
    }
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    printf("Time cost : %.2f ms\n",(end.tv_sec-begin.tv_sec)*1000.0\
            +(end.tv_usec-begin.tv_usec)/1000.0);

    gettimeofday(&begin, NULL);
    for(i = 0; i < times; ++i){
        loop2(LEN, la, lb);
    }
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    printf("Time cost : %.2f ms\n",(end.tv_sec-begin.tv_sec)*1000.0\
            +(end.tv_usec-begin.tv_usec)/1000.0);

    free(la);
    free(lb);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that `n` is large. You can distribute the workload on `k` CPUs by starting `k` threads and provide each with `n/k` elements. Use big chunks of consecutive data for each thread, don't do finegrained interleaving. Try to align the chunks with cache lines.

If you plan to scale to more than one NUMA node, consider to explicitly copy the chunks of workload to the node, the thread runs on, and copy back the results. In this case, it might not really help, because the workload for each step is very simple. You'll have to run tests for that.